# transforming dplyr output for PDF formatting with headings

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, transpose

I'm using Rstudio notebook. 
I've created a dplyr summarise output and I would like to transform it now into a more readable output:

```
df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  dplyr::summarise_all(funs(count = n(),
                           mean = mean, 
                           stdev = sd, 
                           min = min, 
                           max = max, 
                           median = median,
                           iqr = IQR,
                           q25 = quantile(., probs = 0.25),
                           q75 = quantile(., probs = 0.75)
                       ))
```

output wise I get something like this:

```
y   x1_count    x2_count    x3_count    x1_mean x2_mean x3_mean
0   380081       380081      380081       10       12     36
1   19906         19906       19906        5        8     93
```

my question is: how can I transform this into:

```
        count           mean    
    y = 0   y = 1   y = 0   y = 1
x1  380081  19906    10       5
x2  380081  19906    12       8
x3  380081  19906    36      93
```

I tried transpose but did not get the result that I wanted at all.

Comment: How do you plan on using this? The format of having headings (i.e. count and mean) like you might use in an Excel table doesn't really translate to R, where you would generally have a single column name for each column. But since you mention notebooks, are you trying to format into a printed table in a PDF or something? In that case, I've made similar headings with `kableExtra`

Comment: Hi, I know this does not translate in r but I need this in a printed table for a report in a pdf and html for presentation purposes.

Comment: Okay, so that is a different question—you're actually asking about how to reshape data and then format it to knit with grouped headings, probably using a fairly specialized package like `kableExtra` or `huxtable`

Comment: yes true. In my mind it sounded more obvious to first reshape the table itself and then put on the formatting. Didn't know that other options were possible. Still learning to absorb all the possibilities in R which are overwhelming in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I noted in my comment, this is really a two-part question: one is about reshaping the data, but the crux of it is about formatting with headings for a PDF output. The output you're looking for isn't something you would normally achieve in R—you're trying to get repeated column names, and then headings above them. So it's a specifically RMarkdown issue since you're trying to knit to a PDF in this non-standard format.

The first part is the reshaping. You can do this by bringing the data into a long shape, splitting the `x1_count`, etc into `x1` and `count` with `separate`. Then you can label like `y = 0` with `mutate` and `paste`, `unite` to put those values together to make what will be column names like `count_y = 0`, then bring it back into a wide format as you see below.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key = x_measure, value = val, -y) %>%
  separate(x_measure, into = c("x", "measure"), sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(y = paste("y =", y)) %>%
  unite(key, measure, y) %>%
  spread(key = key, value = val)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   x     `count_y = 0` `count_y = 1` `mean_y = 0` `mean_y = 1`
#>   <chr>         <int>         <int>        <int>        <int>
#> 1 x1           380081         19906           10            5
#> 2 x2           380081         19906           12            8
#> 3 x3           380081         19906           36           93
```

Second part is prepping for knitting. There are several packages that let you create these sorts of printed tables—I'm most familiar with `kableExtra`, but there's also [`huxtable`](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/), [`xtable`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html), and likely a few others. Here's a snippet of RMarkdown that I would use to do this with `kableExtra`.

I'm using `rename_all` and `str_remove` to get rid of the bits like `count_` in `count_y = 0`. In order to reshape, I still needed a way to keep the column names unique, but now I can drop those parts of the names.

Then `kableExtra::kable_styling` and `kableExtra::add_header_above` lets you print with a second level of headings. I'd recommend going through the [vignettes](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/), because they're very thorough.

````r
---
title: "Table with headings"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

df %>%
  gather(key = x_measure, value = val, -y) %>%
  separate(x_measure, into = c("x", "measure"), sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(y = paste("y =", y)) %>%
  unite(key, measure, y) %>%
  spread(key = key, value = val) %>%
  rename_all(str_remove, "^[a-z]+_") %>%
  kable(booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "count" = 2, "mean" = 2))
```
````

Knitting this gives a PDF with:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, time and help. Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
df = read.table(text = "
y   x1_count    x2_count    x3_count    x1_mean x2_mean x3_mean
0   380081       380081      380081       10       12     36
1   19906         19906       19906        5        8     93
", header=T)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(col,value,-y) %>%
  separate(col, c("x","metric")) %>%
  mutate(metric = paste0(metric, " for y = ", y)) %>%
  select(-y) %>%
  spread(metric, value)

#    x count for y = 0 count for y = 1 mean for y = 0 mean for y = 1
# 1 x1          380081           19906             10              5
# 2 x2          380081           19906             12              8
# 3 x3          380081           19906             36             93
```

Comment: hi,thank you for your reply and time! As I am rather new to R it is impressive what can be achieved with so little code. I tried your code but get an error now: duplicate identifiers for rows.

Comment: hi, I solved it! there was a variable name with an underscore in it. Thank you for your help and time! much appreciated